# datatable.GetChanges() shows always first row of DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable, bindingsource

I have a DataGridView with a Binding-Source bound to a Data-Table loaded from an Oracle-Database. (btw. I don't think that the Database-Connection could cause this)

I have also a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn bound to an class of persons (only "has" ID and name), so I can display / allow to edit the name instead of the ID. My problem is now that after the data-binding is completed c# automatically "selects" the first cell of the DGV - see the attached picture.

[image]

I also have to use this little piece of code to ensure data integrity:

```
    private void _table_ColumnChanging(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column == _table.Columns["NEEDED_ID"])
        {
            if (e.ProposedValue == null)
            {
                e.ProposedValue = System.DBNull.Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now using this _table.GetChanges() always returns the first row of the DGV as "modified" but the value isn't really changed - it's only `DBNull` instead of `null`. Can I somehow avoid automatic selection of first cell or how to avoid this behavior?

**EDIT:** Meanwhile I found out that changing the first column to something not editable fixes this problem. But this is nothing more than an workaround. I would really appreciate to get an working solution for this.

**EDIT 2:** I have also an empty Object 'on top' of the ComboBox-DataSource

```
  DtoPerson blankPerson = new DtoPerson();
  blankPerson.Name = String.Empty;
  blankPerson.PersonRollenId = -1;
  personList.Add(blankPerson);
```

Comment: regarding EDIT 2: that's not exactly an empty object, you should set your blankPerson's primary key to DBNull.Value. Though IMO, the easier way to solve your problem without touching anything on front-end is to just use UNION SELECT NULL, NULL on your query, ADO.NET will automatically convert those NULLs to corresponding .NET type (i.e. DBNull.Value); I used the same technique, it works. But first, make your DtoPerson's primary key an object type so your ORM/DAL can assign DBNull to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put a null in your DataGridViewComboBoxColumn's DataSource.  example:

```
SELECT id, description
FROM yourTable
UNION
SELECT NULL, NULL
```

Comment: try to make your DtoPerson's primary key an **object** type, so you can push DBNull.Value to the combobox. When you set the DataGridView's DataSource from DataTable, the null value has DBNull.Value

Answer (score 0):

```
GridViewName.ClearSelection();
```